# Why do I get an unexpexted token error while compiling this shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I get the following error

> syntax error unexpected token vertex

I am still learning shaders so I can't really understand the reason for this error.  How can I make this shader work?

```
enter Shader "Custom/VertAnimShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _PosTex("Position texture", 2D) = "black" {}
        _NmlTex("Normal texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Length("Animator lengh", float) = 1
        _DT("Delta time", float) = 0
    }

    SubShader{
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma debug
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #define ts _PosTex_TexelSize

            struct appdata
            {
                float2 uv : TEXTCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXTCOORD0;
                float3 normal: TEXTCOORD1;
                float4  vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex, _PosTex, _NmlTex;
            float4 _PosTex_TexelSize;
            float _Length, _DT;

            v2f vert(appdata v, uint vid: SV_VertexID)
            {
                float t = (_Time.y - _DT) / _Length;
                t = fmod(t, 1.0);
                float x = (vid + 0.5) * ts.x;
                float y = t;
                float4 pos = tex2Dlod(_PosTex, float4(x, y, 0, 0));
                float4 normal = tex2Dlod(_NmlTex, float4(x, y, 0, 0));
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
                o.normal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(normal);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET
            {
                half diff = dot(i.normal, float3(0,1,0))*0.5 + 0.5;
                half4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                return diff * col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct v2f {
    float2 uv : TEXTCOORD0;
    float3 normal: TEXTCOORD1;
    float4 position vertex : SV_POSITION;
};
```

There is a mistake in the last line, it needs to be

```
struct v2f {
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal: TEXCOORD1;
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
};
```

Also note that `TEXTCOORD` needs to be spelled `TEXCOORD`. The tutorial you are using seems to be quite terrible.

This is correctly written later in the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/KUuuXowdYyM?t=2198).

In addition, you are missing a semicolon in the function `vert`: The line

```
o.uv = v.uv
```

needs to be

```
o.uv = v.uv;
```

As of why `ts` is not defined, it's because  you are missing a space character in your `#define`:

```
#define TS_PosTex_TexelSize
```

needs to be `#define TS _PosTex_TexelSize`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even after changing line I am still getting error

Comment: See my edit, there was also another error.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your learning!

Comment: Hello okay this is embarassing but after fixing every typos I am getting another error  program 'vert': unknown input semantics TEXTCOORD/0
 (on d3d11). I updated my question current code after fixing all typos

Comment: @paulp It seems that the tutorial you are using is absolute garbage. `TEXTCOORD` isn't valid, it needs to be spelled `TEXCOORD`.